# Bash: If statement with multiple conditions

Tags: linux, bash, multiple-conditions

I am trying to write a bash script with two conditions.

If first condition is true, check if second condition is true as well.
When both conditions are true, then do this, if one fails, do this.

Executing each condition separate in terminal works, while executing a combined command:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ cat /proc/asound/cards | grep -q 'USB' ] && [ cat /var/www/sync/startmaster | grep -q 'alsa' ]
then
  echo "usb all good"
  #execute command
else
 echo "nothing found"
 #execute other command
fi
```

Throws me an error which I do not understand:

```
 [: missing `]'
grep: ]: No such file or directory
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: remove the square brackets!

Comment: removing square brackets solves the issue!
thank you very much